# How to get username from blog post?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have tried to relationship between post and user so that show the post having the username. But the error has occurred. It has showed the message : **SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.post_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`post_id` in (2))**

```
    //User Model
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

    //Post Model
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', );
    } 

    // Now the post controller
    public function show($id)
    {
      $post = Post::with('user')->find($id);
      return view('posts.show')->with('post',$post);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace with the below code, it's working fine.

```
User Model
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

```
Post model
public function user()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: You mean, change `return $this->hasOne('App\User');` to `return $this->belongsTo('App\User');` ? I believe, a user can have many posts.

Answer (score 2):

**User** has many `Post` so it would be **hasMany** relationship. 
**Post** belongs to (depends on) **User**, so it would be **belongsTo**.

**User Model** :

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

**Post Model** :

```
public function user()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```